# Passar imagens a frente em um Slider

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/FeedNoticias/js/jssor.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="modules/FeedNoticias/js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

        var _CaptionTransitions = [];
        _CaptionTransitions["L"] = { $Duration: 900, x: 0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["R"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["T"] = { $Duration: 900, y: 0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["B"] = { $Duration: 900, y: -0.6, $Easing: { $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutSine }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["ZMF|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|10"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInExpo }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTT|2"] = { $Duration: 900, $Zoom: 3, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInQuad }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.5} };
        _CaptionTransitions["RTTL|BR"] = { $Duration: 900, x: -0.6, y: -0.6, $Zoom: 11, $Rotate: 1, $Easing: { $Left: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Top: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Zoom: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic, $Opacity: $JssorEasing$.$EaseLinear, $Rotate: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInCubic }, $Opacity: 2, $Round: { $Rotate: 0.8} };
        _CaptionTransitions["CLIP|LR"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 15, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic }, $Opacity: 2 };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|L"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 1, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic} };
        _CaptionTransitions["MCLIP|R"] = { $Duration: 900, $Clip: 2, $Move: true, $Easing: { $Clip: $JssorEasing$.$EaseInOutCubic} };

        var options = {
            $FillMode: 2,                                       //[Optional] The way to fill image in slide, 0 stretch, 1 contain (keep aspect ratio and put all inside slide), 2 cover (keep aspect ratio and cover whole slide), 4 actual size, 5 contain for large image, actual size for small image, default value is 0
            $AutoPlay: true,                                    //[Optional] Whether to auto play, to enable slideshow, this option must be set to true, default value is false
            $AutoPlayInterval: 3000,                            //[Optional] Interval (in milliseconds) to go for next slide since the previous stopped if the slider is auto playing, default value is 3000
            $PauseOnHover: 0,                                   //[Optional] Whether to pause when mouse over if a slider is auto playing, 0 no pause, 1 pause for desktop, 2 pause for touch device, 3 pause for desktop and touch device, 4 freeze for desktop, 8 freeze for touch device, 12 freeze for desktop and touch device, default value is 1

            $ArrowKeyNavigation: true,                          //[Optional] Allows keyboard (arrow key) navigation or not, default value is false
            $SlideEasing: $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuint,          //[Optional] Specifies easing for right to left animation, default value is $JssorEasing$.$EaseOutQuad
            $SlideDuration: 800,                               //[Optional] Specifies default duration (swipe) for slide in milliseconds, default value is 500
            $MinDragOffsetToSlide: 20,                          //[Optional] Minimum drag offset to trigger slide , default value is 20
            //$SlideWidth: 600,                                 //[Optional] Width of every slide in pixels, default value is width of 'slides' container
            //$SlideHeight: 300,                                //[Optional] Height of every slide in pixels, default value is height of 'slides' container
            $SlideSpacing: 0,                                   //[Optional] Space between each slide in pixels, default value is 0
            $DisplayPieces: 1,                                  //[Optional] Number of pieces to display (the slideshow would be disabled if the value is set to greater than 1), the default value is 1
            $ParkingPosition: 0,                                //[Optional] The offset position to park slide (this options applys only when slideshow disabled), default value is 0.
            $UISearchMode: 1,                                   //[Optional] The way (0 parellel, 1 recursive, default value is 1) to search UI components (slides container, loading screen, navigator container, arrow navigator container, thumbnail navigator container etc).
            $PlayOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to play slide (for auto play, navigation), 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 5 horizental reverse, 6 vertical reverse, default value is 1
            $DragOrientation: 1,                                //[Optional] Orientation to drag slide, 0 no drag, 1 horizental, 2 vertical, 3 either, default value is 1 (Note that the $DragOrientation should be the same as $PlayOrientation when $DisplayPieces is greater than 1, or parking position is not 0)

            $CaptionSliderOptions: {                            //[Optional] Options which specifies how to animate caption
                $Class: $JssorCaptionSlider$,                   //[Required] Class to create instance to animate caption
                $CaptionTransitions: _CaptionTransitions,       //[Required] An array of caption transitions to play caption, see caption transition section at jssor slideshow transition builder
                $PlayInMode: 1,                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes after main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes after main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
                $PlayOutMode: 3                                 //[Optional] 0 None (no play), 1 Chain (goes before main slide), 3 Chain Flatten (goes before main slide and flatten all caption animations), default value is 1
            },

            $BulletNavigatorOptions: {                          //[Optional] Options to specify and enable navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorBulletNavigator$,                 //[Required] Class to create navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 2,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 1,                                 //[Optional] Auto center navigator in parent container, 0 None, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1,                                      //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
                $Lanes: 1,                                      //[Optional] Specify lanes to arrange items, default value is 1
                $SpacingX: 8,                                   //[Optional] Horizontal space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $SpacingY: 8,                                   //[Optional] Vertical space between each item in pixel, default value is 0
                $Orientation: 1                                 //[Optional] The orientation of the navigator, 1 horizontal, 2 vertical, default value is 1
            },

            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {                           //[Optional] Options to specify and enable arrow navigator or not
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$,                  //[Requried] Class to create arrow navigator instance
                $ChanceToShow: 1,                               //[Required] 0 Never, 1 Mouse Over, 2 Always
                $AutoCenter: 2,                                 //[Optional] Auto center arrows in parent container, 0 No, 1 Horizontal, 2 Vertical, 3 Both, default value is 0
                $Steps: 1                                       //[Optional] Steps to go for each navigation request, default value is 1
            }
        };

        var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$("slider1_container", options);

        //responsive code begin
        //you can remove responsive code if you don't want the slider scales while window resizes
        function ScaleSlider() {
            var bodyWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
            if (bodyWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 1920));
            else
                window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 30);
        }
        ScaleSlider();

        $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider);
        $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider);
        //responsive code end
    });
</script>
<!-- Jssor Slider Begin -->
<!-- To move inline styles to css file/block, please specify a class name for each element. --> 
<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; margin: 0 auto;
    top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">
    <!-- Loading Screen -->
    <div u="loading" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
        <div style="filter: alpha(opacity=70); opacity: 0.7; position: absolute; display: block;
            top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        </div>
        <div style="position: absolute; display: block; background: url(img/loading.gif) no-repeat center center;
            top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Slides Container -->
   <div u="slides" style="cursor: move; position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 1300px;
        height: 500px; overflow: hidden;">


                    <?php 

            include ("coneccao.php");
            $query = "SELECT feednoticias.id as 'ID',feednoticias.titulo as 'Titulo', feednoticias.texto as 'Texto', feednoticias.caminho_img as 'Caminho', feednoticias.data_not as 'Data' FROM feednoticias ORDER BY feednoticias.data_not desc;";
            $resultado = mysqli_query($ligacao, $query);


            for($i = 1; $i<=10 ; $i++){
                $linha = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);
                ${"imagem".($i)."_ID"} = $linha["ID"];
                ${"imagem".($i)."_Titulo"} = $linha["Titulo"];
                ${"imagem".($i)."_Texto"} = $linha["Texto"];
                ${"imagem".($i)."_Caminho"} = $linha["Caminho"];
                ${"imagem".($i)."_Data"} = $linha["Data"];

            }
            for($a = 1 ; $a<=10 ; $a++){                    
                if(isset(${'imagem'.$a.'_ID'})){                    ?>
        <div>
            <img style="position: relative; width: 100%; height:120%" src="<?php echo ${"imagem".$a."_Caminho"}; ?>" />
            <div style="position: absolute; width: 1000px; height: 60px; top: 30px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                text-align: left; line-height: 60px; text-transform: uppercase; font-size: 35px;
                    color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <font color="#E6AA00" style="-webkit-text-stroke-width: 2px; -webkit-text-stroke-color: black; font-weight: bold; "><?php echo ${"imagem".$a."_Titulo"}; ?></font>
            </div>
            <div style="background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.85); position: absolute; width: 480px; height: 120px; top: 300px; left: 30px; padding: 5px;
                text-align: left; line-height: 36px; font-size: 15px;
                    color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <?php echo substr("${"imagem".$a."_Texto"}",0,170)." ..."; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php 
        } else {
        echo "Imagem não encontrada.";          
        }
    }

?>

    </div>


    <!--#region Bullet Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-bullet-navigator-jquery.html -->
    <style>
        /* jssor slider bullet navigator skin 21 css */
        /*
        .jssorb21 div           (normal)
        .jssorb21 div:hover     (normal mouseover)
        .jssorb21 .av           (active)
        .jssorb21 .av:hover     (active mouseover)
        .jssorb21 .dn           (mousedown)
        */
        .jssorb21 {
            position: absolute;
        }
        .jssorb21 div, .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av {
            position: absolute;
            /* size of bullet elment */
            width: 19px;
            height: 19px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 19px;
            color: white;
            font-size: 12px;
            background: url(modules/FeedNoticias/img/Slider/b21.png) no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .jssorb21 div { background-position: -5px -5px; }
        .jssorb21 div:hover, .jssorb21 .av:hover { background-position: -35px -5px; }
        .jssorb21 .av { background-position: -65px -5px; }
        .jssorb21 .dn, .jssorb21 .dn:hover { background-position: -95px -5px; }
    </style>

    <!--#region Arrow Navigator Skin Begin -->
    <!-- Help: http://www.jssor.com/development/slider-with-arrow-navigator-jquery.html -->
    <style>
        /* jssor slider arrow navigator skin 21 css */
        /*
        .jssora21l                  (normal)
        .jssora21r                  (normal)
        .jssora21l:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora21r:hover            (normal mouseover)
        .jssora21l.jssora21ldn      (mousedown)
        .jssora21r.jssora21rdn      (mousedown)
        */
        .jssora21l, .jssora21r {
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            /* size of arrow element */
            width: 55px;
            height: 55px;
            cursor: pointer;
            background: url(modules/FeedNoticias/img/Slider/a21.png) center center no-repeat;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        .jssora21l { background-position: -3px -33px; }
        .jssora21r { background-position: -63px -33px; }
        .jssora21l:hover { background-position: -123px -33px; }
        .jssora21r:hover { background-position: -183px -33px; }
        .jssora21l.jssora21ldn { background-position: -243px -33px; }
        .jssora21r.jssora21rdn { background-position: -303px -33px; }
    </style>
    <!-- Arrow Left -->
    <span u="arrowleft" class="jssora21l" style="top: 123px; left: 8px;">
    </span>
    <!-- Arrow Right -->
    <span u="arrowright" class="jssora21r" style="top: 123px; right: 8px;">
    </span>
    <!--#endregion Arrow Navigator Skin End -->
    <a style="display: none" href="http://www.jssor.com">Carousel Slider</a>
</div>
<!-- Jssor Slider End -->
```

Basicamente ele passa uma imagem á frente. Por exemplo: começa na imagem 10 e passa para a 8, mas dá para ver a 9 a passar.

Comment: Sua pergunta está um tanto confusa, tente dar uma organizada. Recomendo ler [este tópico](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) da central de ajuda.

Comment: Consegue colocar no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) pra exemplificar?

Comment: O tamanho das imagens q usa sao diferentes ou sao png com transparencias? como consegue "ver passar" as demais?